# Transform 2 dimensional array to nested structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to transform 2-dimensional array to the nested structure as shown below in javascript.

Input:

[[A,B,C],[A,B,E],[A,M,N]]

Output:

```
[ {"name":A,"children":
        [{"name":B,"children":
            [{"name":C,"children":[]},{"name":E,"children":[]}]
        },
        {"name":M,"children":
            [{"name":N,"children":[]}]
        }]
   }
]
```

Please let me know if there is any elegant solution to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any solution? Have you tried anything and had problems or found your solutions inelegant?

Comment: I constructed a map out of 2-dimensional array by specifying parent in it for each level.  ex:-map.push {"name":B,"parent":A}. With this map I thought of building hierarchy. I am not sure if it is elegant solution

Comment: Am I to assume that the empty child nodes in the output along with the lack of quotes around the input elements  means the depth of the tree is dependent on a property of the object? Or can the output shape be considered stable for this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the arrays in your array-of-arrays are actually paths through a tree and you're trying to build the subtrees that those paths describe then you could create and cache nodes as needed:

```
# cache.by_id could be seen as a bit of a hack, don't
# forget to reset it in real life (or wrap this up in
# a class and use an instance variable for `by_id`).
cache = (id) ->
  if id of cache.by_id
    there = true
  else
    cache.by_id[id] = { name: id, children: [ ] }
    there = false
  [cache.by_id[id], there]
cache.by_id = { }
```

and then an easy way to build the paths in the tree:

```
push = (parent, id) ->
  [child, there] = cache(id)
  parent?.children.push(child) if(!there)
  child
```

Then you can loop through the paths:

```
paths = [
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['A', 'B', 'E'],
  ['A', 'M', 'N'],
  ['A', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
]

for path in paths
  parent = null
  for child in path
    parent = push(parent, child)
```

or:

```
for path in paths
  path.reduce(push, null)
```

Then look at `cache.by_id.A`. Or keep track of the roots as you go by tracking parents in the cache (so that the roots will be nodes without parents) or directly track roots in `push` with another object (add it as a root `if !there`, remove it as a possible root `if parent`).

Elegant? Maybe. Looks clean and easy to understand to me at least.